# How can I build an apk from 'apktool d -s -o' folder

Tags: build, package, apk, apktool

I run `apktool d -s -o foldername` first to decode an apk file.So the classes.dex remained in the folder.Then I replace the classes.dex file and wanna package a new apkfile.So I run `apktool b foldername` on the terminal.But errors came up:

```
I: Using Apktool 2.0.3
I: Checking whether resources has changed...
I: Building resources...
res/drawable/$ic_launcher_foreground__0.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-zA-Z0-9_.]
A/        ( 6108): First type is not attr!
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [/var/folders/1x/rbs7f_y145qf3f9dbbzktwlw0000gn/T/brut_util_Jar_7766331736141549579.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 27, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, -F, /var/folders/1x/rbs7f_y145qf3f9dbbzktwlw0000gn/T/APKTOOL1668967197700881167.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, version, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/eilir/Library/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/eilir/work6/安卓/new3/res, -M, /Users/eilir/work6/安卓/new3/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:472)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:410)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:298)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:268)
    at brut.apktool.Main.cmdBuild(Main.java:225)
    at brut.apktool.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [/var/folders/1x/rbs7f_y145qf3f9dbbzktwlw0000gn/T/brut_util_Jar_7766331736141549579.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 27, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, -F, /var/folders/1x/rbs7f_y145qf3f9dbbzktwlw0000gn/T/APKTOOL1668967197700881167.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, version, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/eilir/Library/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/eilir/work6/安卓/new3/res, -M, /Users/eilir/work6/安卓/new3/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:425)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:458)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command: [/var/folders/1x/rbs7f_y145qf3f9dbbzktwlw0000gn/T/brut_util_Jar_7766331736141549579.tmp, p, --forced-package-id, 127, --min-sdk-version, 27, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 1, --version-name, 1.0, -F, /var/folders/1x/rbs7f_y145qf3f9dbbzktwlw0000gn/T/APKTOOL1668967197700881167.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, version, -0, arsc, -I, /Users/eilir/Library/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /Users/eilir/work6/安卓/new3/res, -M, /Users/eilir/work6/安卓/new3/AndroidManifest.xml]
    at brut.util.OS.exec(OS.java:89)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:419)
    ... 6 more
```

I supposed that's because the classes.dex file remaining in the folder.How should I do?

Comment: I'm trying to install an `apkbuilder` command line tool .But no useful docs found.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanna replace the classes.dex file in the apk.If in Windows ,that's easy to do with RAR software , but no way on MacOS.